# Use Encapsulation method how to write the program

Tags: oop, getter-setter, encapsulation, getter, setter

Example Program 1
Step 1: Create a class 'Number'
Step 2: Declare Non-Static field/variable.
Step 3: Create another class ‘EncapTest’.
Step 4: Create an object of class Number.
Step 5: Print the values in the variable.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Number
{
private:
    int var1;
public:
Number(){var1=0;}
Number(int var1)
{ this->var1=var1; }
void setValue(int var1=0)
{
   this->var1 = var1;
}
int getValue()
{  return var1; }
};

 class EncapTest
{   
private:
Number obj;
public:
EncapTest () {obj.setValue();}
EncapTest (int var1) 
{ obj.setValue(var1); }
void showOutput()
{
 cout << "The value stored in variable is: " << obj.getValue()<<endl;
 }
};

int main ()
 {
  EncapTest object (3);
   object.showOutput();

  return 0;
  }
```